# How to deal with already treated file in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Let's imagine I have a `raw_data` folder with files that i want to transform and then load to `clean_data` folder. I want my DAG to sniff the `raw_data` folder and only treat the file that have been not transformed and loaded before.
For this I would use a log file to track which file i already have treated as follow but I am not sure this is the best way to proceed.

**How do you proceed to ignore files that are already treated, may be there is a built in function in Apache Airflow ?**

My directory would as follow

```
│   extract.py
│   track_actions.log
│
├───clean_data
└───raw_data
        file1.txt
        file2.txt
        file3.txt
```

My Dag function would be as follow

```
import os
import shutil

raw_files = os.listdir('./raw_data')


# would be my dag function

with open('track_actions.log', 'r') as log_file:
    already_treated_files = log_file.read().split()

    with open('track_actions.log', 'w') as log_file:
        for filename in raw_files:
            if filename not in already_treated_files:
                # apply some transformation here
                shutil.copy(f'./raw_data/{filename}', f'./clean_data/{filename[:-4]}_transformed.txt')
                log_file.write(filename + '\n')
            else:
                print(filename, 'already treated')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming data in your "raw_data" folder arrives periodically and you want Airflow to process it. Airflow has the notion of "runtime context", which are several variables at runtime which contain information about e.g. the start and end date of the interval. See `data_interval_start` and `data_interval_end` in the documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html.

In your function, you could select files with a creation date within that interval, and schedule your DAG to run e.g. once an hour (depending on how often your data arrives). You would then only process files created in the last hour.

Comment: Oh ok thanks ! I will consider this option.